# Repeated JEE JPA typed queries always going to the DB... 1st level cache confusion

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss

I thought I had a pretty clear understanding of JPA 1st level cache.  However, while testing my JEE Msg driven bean (JBOSS JPA 2.0) with the associated persistence.xml file setting "hibernate.show_sql" set to true I see sql behavior which I don't know how to reconcile.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
logger.info("Getting widget by query. Sql should be issued");
TypedQuery<Widget> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT w FROM Widget w WHERE w.widgetId = :id", Widget.class);
query.setParameter("id", 1);
// This should go to the db
Widget widget = query.getSingleResult();

logger.info("Getting widget by query again.  No sql should be issued");
TypedQuery<Widget> query2 = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT w FROM Widget w WHERE w.widgetId = :id", Widget.class);
query2.setParameter("id", 1);

Widget widget2 = query2.getSingleResult();

logger.info("Getting widget by entity manager find.  No sql should be issued");
entityManager.find(Widget.class, 1);
```

From the above I'd expect, 1 database select statement in the logging but, what I see is a select statement for both getSingleResult() statements, which confuses me.  Can someone please explain this?  Please note, the find does not result in a sql logging statement.  Also the other thing I noticed is if I do not put a Where clause in the above createQuery statements and change the getSingleResult() statements to getResultList() statements, their execution also results in two Select statements going to the database.  I verified this via the hibernate logging and a debug session where I inserted a row between the first and second statements using sqlplus.  With regard to createQuery() and where clauses shouldn't the entity manager be smart enough to known it already loaded the results of a given query?  In the previous example shouldn't the entity manager understand it already loaded all the Widget entities?  Please note, when I view the objects and do equality checks the entity manager is managing them appropriately (ie no two objects referring to the same db table row).

Comment: L1 cache operates on objects retrieved from a query ... so it uses the already cached objects. That will NEVER prevent the query being executed, just that the results may not be used. Query results cache != L1 Cache

Comment: @NeilStockton very true, the only time it may prevent queries from repeating is for lazy inits that have already been triggered before.

Comment: Ok so that i understand... In the case where I added a row (described above) I suppose the entity manger checks id or something such that the result included the new row plus the already fetched rows .... so if I did something like add a row and update a row that was already loaded the result would include the new row but not the updated row

Comment: BTW thanks for the commennts/answers

Answer (score -1):

Query caching (unlike object caching) is not something enabled by default.  You need to use the appropriate query hint (`@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable",value="true")` or `query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)`).

(I am, of course, silently assuming that you have set the `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` property to `true` in `persistence.xml`)

A word of warning: relying on query caching too much may lead to hard-to-detect bugs (which is why JPA is smart enough not to enable it by default). Make sure to see the relevant docs (e.g. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html) on how to handle it properly.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This answers the question why issuing the same JPA query twice does not by default cause a SQL query execute only once. Isn't that what is being asked here?